# Valid number of Cat 6 + Coax cables for pipe conduit?

Tags: wiring, cables, ethernet, coaxial-cable, cable-management

Here's some old wiring done in my absence as my parents could only monitor so much.

Hate the use of Skinnier version on Flexi Pipe that won't allow any movement or pull once initial install is done. Crappy. 
(Hidden behind the black pipe)

[image: flexi pipe 2 cat 6 + c1 coax]

2 Cat 6 + 1 Coax

It comes out over here at one of these pipes. I forget which one (we traced it w physical push pull)

[image: conduit pipe 3/4 or 1 inch]

Conduit Pipe is 3/4 or 1 inch. Need to check in morning.

Now I saw a link on SE which showed 5 cables inside a 3/4 inch conduit.
[How many CAT6 cables can fit in 3/4 conduit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/71692/how-many-cat6-cables-can-fit-in-3-4-conduit?rq=1)   + 2nd Answer shows Chart with different variations.

This old school electrician guy is helping me out so we trying to figure out & have some debates.

- He is saying there's no way we can add a 3rd Cat 6 given the thick Coax we have.
- Now I'm wondering if this was due to the flexible piping being the cause of his thought.

If we were to avoid flexible Pipe and do the following;

- Only straight Runs
- only use pull/ junction boxes or none at hidden turn locations (concealed above ceiling)
- Use straight or 135 degree angle at 1-2 places through a wall (if at all we have to do that) will try to avoid.

**What kind of Cat 6 + Coax additions/ increases could we do to the existing bunch?**

Or do we for for 1" or a Second Conduit to add more.  Thoughts?

Assume new conduit and flexible piping drama / flaws be eliminated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why wouldn't a switch eliminate the need for a new run?

Comment: So as a networking guy I should put switches all over the place in my concealed false ceiling, one for each run of Cat 6. . Each run represents a full gigabit connect. The fact that I'm asking for multiple Cat 6 runs should be clear why. And I'm to detail out the physical & network layout of the condo for you, to ask about a wiring pull ft question?